# Google authentication using Xamarin.Auth

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing an application using Xamarin.Android.

I need to enable login with Facebook and Google and I choose to use the Xamarin.Auth component.
I got it work with facebook but I have some issue with Google.

This is my code:

```
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
            clientId: "myId.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            clientSecret: "mysecred",
            scope: "openid",
            authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
            redirectUrl: new Uri ("myredirect:oob"),
            accessTokenUrl: new Uri ("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"),
            getUsernameAsync: null
        ); 

        activity.StartActivity (auth.GetUI (activity));

        auth.Completed += (sender, e) => {
            Console.WriteLine (e.IsAuthenticated);
        };
```

Is this way the Google Activity is displayed, and I can insert my Username and password. But when I click the google login button I get a message like this:

> google auth please copy this code switch to your application and paste it there [code]

What I have to do with that code? I just need to get the user name/lastname/email/id.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you got any work around for this problem?

Comment: @user3471528, did you get the solution for this

Answer (score 3):

Bellow steps worked for me.

1.register in google developer console as webapplication instead of installed application(android)* provide the redirect url with valid url ("http://abcd.com/xyz.aspx") same should be used in the application code.

2.on authentication complete it will return access_token

3.by using the access_token make the REST request to get user complete information (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + accessTokenValue + “.)

4.Deserialize the json response to get information in object.

check the source code :http://appliedcodelog.blogspot.in/2015/08/login-by-google-account-integration-for.html

Comment: Hi Suchit, Last 2 day I am trying to use your code to make Google Plus Login in Xamarin Android. But I failed. I have looked your article, Xamarin Form discussion and try each and every thing but still facing issue. Please help.

Comment: In step 3: When I try to access user information using access token then 403 error occur in response. JSON like this:  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

Comment: I have also tried to make new client Id but it still showing same error

Comment: Ensure that access token has not been expired.

Comment: No it does not expire, when I got access token in another sec I hit to access user information.

Comment: Today when I tired it shows : code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"

Comment: But you did not reference what the question was , @user3471528, wanted you to answer his question according to Xamarin.Auth